# VM: UITableViewLabel eating up memory iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments

When I scroll UITableView the memory keeps on increasing and I get this sort of results when I run "Allocations".

[image: Allocations] I see their that **VM:UITableViewLabel** memory keeps on increasing and is persistent, Is their any way to I could remove this constant increase in memory

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

    {
        NSString *text = @"";
        BOOL defaultStyle = YES;


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *defaultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (defaultCell == nil) {
        defaultCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"reusing the cell");
    }

    defaultCell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    defaultCell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    defaultCell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26.0f];

    UIImageView *iv = defaultCell.imageView;


    int totalSections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
    NSInteger computedSection = indexPath.section;

    if (defaultStyle)
    {
        defaultCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        defaultCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        defaultCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    else if (computedSection == 0)
    {
        const int totalRows  = [self tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            text = @"Style1";
            defaultStyle = NO;
            if (self.style1 == nil)
            {
                defaultCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                defaultCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            }
            else
            {
                defaultCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
                defaultCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }
            iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Style1.png"];

        }

        if(indexPath.row == totalRows - 2){
            // Categories
            text = @"Style2";
            iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Style2.png"];
            defaultStyle = NO;

            if ( self.style2 == nil) {
                defaultCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                defaultCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            } else {
                defaultCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
                defaultCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == totalRows - 1){
            // Search
            text = @"Style3";
            iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Style3.png"];
        }

    }
    else if (computedSection == 1)
    {

        MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [mTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomTableCellIdentifier];

        if ( cell == nil ) {
            cell = [CustomTableViewCell loadFromNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell"];
        }
        cell.titleLabel = @"custom cell";
        cell.openImage =[UIImage imageNamed: @"custom.png"]
        return cell;

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == totalSections - 1)
    {

        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            text = @"Account";
            defaultStyle = NO;
            if (self.hasAccount == nil)
            {
                defaultCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                defaultCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            }
            else
            {
                defaultCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
                defaultCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            }

            iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Account.png"];
        }
    }

    defaultCell.textLabel.text = text;
    return defaultCell;
}
```

Comment: Could you also show the header of `ProgrammeTableViewCell` class, and an implementation of its `dealloc` method?

Comment: What is `loadFromNibNamed:` method you're using to load `ProgrammeTableViewCell`? If it is just a common wrapper for `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`, it is likely written for ARC environment, while you're using non-ARC, so you can easily mess with autoreleasing there. Also there's `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, which automatically create cell from NIB if needed and remove the burden of `if (cell == nil)` checks. And hey, why non-ARC at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied your code into a new project, and made some tests. It has never used more than 10 Mb memory on a real device, so there can be 2 cases.

1. Calling a method which leaks. At this point you call only one method in cellForRow because: `BOOL defaultStyle = YES;` This method is: 
   `int totalSections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];`
   Could you post also this method please?
2. UITableViewCell subclass leaks while reusing. This isn't an option now since you are using UITableViewCell.

Small note #1: remove the autorelease if the project is in ARC.

Small note #2: Use

`static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *defaultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

instead of:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *defaultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (defaultCell == nil) {
    defaultCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"reusing the cell");
}
```

and you don't need to check and alloc new cells manually.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your help, the following solution worked for me

1.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:kDefaultCellIdentifier];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:kCustomTableCellIdentifier];
}
```

as told by @Péter Kovács

2.

Used indexPath method for both cells

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = kDefaultCellIdentifier;
    UITableViewCell *defaultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = kCustomTableViewCellIdentifer;
    UITableViewCell *defaultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

3.

Main problem I was using the defaultCell **globally**, it dequeued the defaultCell also for the CustomTableViewCell, so in the case CustomTableViewCell block was triggered it dequeued two cells. Dequeue ing respective cell based on their rows solved the problem.

Comment: Not so elegant if you accept my answer, then you make a solution comment based on my answer, and accept your own answer instead of mine. :D Ofc, it's not problem, I'm happy I could help. :)

Comment: ok accepted your answer by the way your answer didnt answer my exact problem see the third point that was my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not reusing the cells used in your table view

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
} else {
    // reset your cell values here
}
```

Use this inside your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: I am already using it, and I can see it in the logs that it is reusing the cell

Comment: Boolean variable defaultStyle is always YES when it reaches the if condition. So it always satisfies the if condition. Can you please check whether that is causing any issues?